# Hundred or hundreds (for unit-less numbers)?

Tags: grammatical-number, numerals

Which is correct?

The molecular weight of this substance ranges from

1. two hundred to two hundred and sixty.
2. two hundreds to two hundred and sixty.

I need to spell the numbers out for some reasons and I'm stuck.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hundred is singular.  You would use the plural if, for example, you were counting currency ("that's two hundreds, one fifty, three twenties, a ten, and four ones").

Comment: If you thought "two hundreds" was OK, why not "two hundreds and sixty". You are not consistent.

Comment: Also you don't need *and* unless you are adding numbers.

Comment: You say two hundred, not two hundreds.  You don't adgh

Comment: @fixer1234 Thank you! Your answer prompted me to read my dictionaries again. With your comment in mind, I understand the definitions more. "Hundred" is a singular noun. That's simple!

Comment: @user3169   Yes, your first answer made me realize it.  Thank you!
Regarding your second answer, I understand it this way: "and" in this kind of phrase is less common nowadays than before.

Comment: @Khan   Thank you for the suggestion.  I didn't understand "adgh", so if it's important, let me know the meaning.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to use any number word in English.

The first is as a cardinal number. In this case, it's invariable. It doesn't show the plural.

> **A hundred** and five cows.
>
> **Two thousand** is more than I expected.
>
> **Forty million**, **seven hundred thousand** and sixty-three accounts have been opened.

The second use is as a common noun, with the meaning "batch of N". This use is countable, and it does show the plural.

> There are **hundreds** of people here.
>   
> *→ There are several hundred people here.*
>
> **Dozens** of species go extinct every day.
>   
> *→ Several dozen species go extinct every day.*
>
> We spend **billions** of dollars on national defence.
>   
> *→ We spend several billion of dollars on national defence.*

Even small numbers can be counted this way.

> They left the building in **twos** and **threes**.
>   
> *→They left the building in groups of two and in groups of three.*

There are a few other quirks to how we use number words, but those are the broad strokes.

Comment: Your answer helps.  So, the first one applies to my case, and cardinal numbers are invariable.  Thank you so much!!